# Finding nearest point in an efficient way

Tags: c++, algorithm, geometry

I've got a point in 2d plane for example (x0,y0) and a set of n points (x1,y1)...(xn,yn) and I want to find nearest point to (x0,y0) in a way better than  trying all points. Any solutions?

I should also say that my points are sorted in this way:

```
bool less(point a,point b){
  if(a.x!=b.x)
     return a.x<b.x;
  else
     return a.y<b.y;
 }
```

Comment: Is x0 and y0 the first element in that sorted list of points?

Comment: no. It is completely out of the list :D

Comment: Is the point arbitrary? Does it change? That is, will you later want to find the nearest point to some _other_ point?

Comment: I may want to query for many different points

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a quad-tree for 2D
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Answer (score 10):

[Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram) is designed specifically for finding nearest point very fast. Although it's quite a pain to implement, you might find some existing library/implementation.

There's also an option to of repeatedly dividing plane in squares, thus building some kind of tree where each non-leaf node has 4 children (top-right square, bottom-right square, etc.). Then, of four squares you find the one your point is in and proceed with it recursively. Often this yields point close enough, so you may eliminate the need to check other squares.
But it's easy to create a 'counter-example' for this strategy which will result in linear time.

But there's not much you can do with your sorted array to speed up the process. You'll need a special data structure.

**edit**
Second structure is called *Quadtree*, thanks to **VGE** for providing the name.

Comment: Although it may seem overkill, you spend O(n log n) operations building your Voronoi diagram, but afterwards, each nearest neighbor can be looked up in O(log n) time. Contrast this with O(n) for naive iteration. Also, I recommand using CGAL for computing the Voronoi diagram (by Delaunay triangulation). CGAL is complicated, but the Delaunay algorithm is very sensitive to roundoff errors and you should not implement it yourself: you need (among others) adaptative precision floating point numbers.

Comment: Only problem is to implement the data structure :-). Also, CGAL is quite an expensive library unless you are open-sourcing your own code.

Comment: @Daniel: I did not know cgal was dual licensed. The data structure is in fact quite natural. The real problem lies in the unstable test of "being in a circumscribed circle of a triangle": if the triangle points are almost aligned, the computation is very unaccurate and yields the wrong triangulation.

Comment: @Alexandre Yes I am very well aware of this problem :-). I've spent months working on a triangulation algorithm trying to fix it. Of course I didn't succeed and the bad code is still used by unfortunate clients...

Comment: @Daniel: I'm afraid you have to use adaptive floating point computations. There are a lot of ways to do this, I may have some papers handy if you're interested.

Answer (score 7):

For efficient nearest neighbour search you need to use a spatial partitioning scheme, for example a [*k*d-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kd-tree).

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't using any sort of tree data structure to help limit the range of values you have to query, you are going to have to check each point in your range of potential "neighbors".  One way to limit the comparisons would be to check the squared distance from your given point for the smallest value:

```
Point myPoint = {x, y};
std::vector<Point> otherPoints; // given list of points to check

struct PointDistance
{
    Point pt;
    float dist;
};

std::vector<PointDistance> squaredDistances(otherPoints.size()); // will be filled in with squared distances

float CalculateDistance(const Point& pt1, const Point& pt2)
{
    float deltaX = pt1.x - pt2.x;
    float deltaY = pt1.y - pt2.y;
    return (deltaX * deltaX) + (deltaY * deltaY);
}

// should be changed to use an algorithm, but for clarity done as a loop here
for (int i = 0; i < otherPoints.size(); ++i)
{
    PointDistance pd;
    pd.pt = otherPoints[i];
    pd.dist = CalculateDistance(myPoint, pd.pt);
    squaredDistances.push_back(pd);
}

bool DistanceLess(const PointDistance& lhs, const PointDistance& rhs)
{
    return lhs.dist < rhs.dist;
}

std::sort(squaredDistances.begin(), squaredDistances.end(), DistanceLess);

// squaredDistances[0].pt will be your closest point.
```

Comment: `std::min_element()` provides the answer with less complexity (max(N-1,0) comparisons) than `std::sort()` (O(N·log(N))). Exempting error handling, this yields the closest point: `std::min_element(...)->pt`.

Comment: @MartinMoene Yes, `std::min_element` is a good alternative to sorting the squared distances for just the minimum element.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the set of N points then instead of just pushing them into a set, you can hash and map them based on their linear distance from the point under consideration . So points with same linear distance will be in the same bucket. Then fetching the point(s) based on distance will be a constant time operation.

Answer (score 0):

A particularly nice solution is [ANN: A Library for Approximate Nearest Neighbor Searching.](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~mount/ANN/) I've used it for point location in triangulations. You initialize a data structure with points, in my case I used the center points of my triangles. Then you can pass in another point and get back list of the approximate closest neighbour points. Even the number of points returned is selectable as a parameter. Anyway ANN was a great library for my purposes, I'd suggest you check it out.

Good luck!