# Get all coordinates between two points of a polyline when clicked

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, map-projections

I have set up a [sample polyline](http://jsfiddle.net/himal/S66sR/3/) from given coordinates.

```
coordinates = [
                    [52.908902047770276,-116.015625],
                    [52.908902047770276,-116.015625],
                    [53.12040528310657,-115.6640625],
                    [53.12040528310657,-115.6640625],
                    [53.33087298301704,-115.6640625],
                    [53.33087298301704,-115.6640625],
                    [53.74871079689897,-115.6640625],
                    [53.74871079689897,-115.6640625],
                    [54.36775852406841,-115.6640625],
                    [54.36775852406841,-115.6640625],
                    [54.97761367069625,-115.3125],
......]
```

When the polyline is clicked, the returned coordinates do not match the coordinates from which the polyline was built.

Is there a way to get all the coordinates between two points of the polyline that belong to the given list of coordinates when the polyline is clicked ?

Also when the map is zoomed, the clicked marker goes off the path off the polyline.

Comment: It might help to see some of your code, other than just an array of coordinates

Comment: possible duplicate of [right click on google map polyline isn't actually “on” the polyline](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19172433/right-click-on-google-map-polyline-isnt-actually-on-the-polyline/19179716#19179716)

Comment: You are placing the marker where you clicked the polyline. Not on the closest waypoint if that's what you want to do? Clarify: *get coordinates between 2 points when polyline is clicked*. When you click  the polyline, you click one point, not two. So which 2 points do you want?