# Projecting a point onto a path

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geolocation, latitude-longitude

Suppose I have an ordered array containing points `(lat, lon)` describing a path, and I also have a point `(lat, lon)` describing my current location.

How can I project the point onto the path (and place the point in the appropriate place in the array)?

What I tried is just simply by searching for the nearest two points and assume it's in the middle of them. It's a good guess, but sometimes fails.

What would be a good way of doing this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find a point in a polyline which is closest to a latlng](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429562/find-a-point-in-a-polyline-which-is-closest-to-a-latlng)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I see it like this:**

[image: line segment overview]

- `p0,p1` are path line segment endpoints
- `p` is your position
- `q'` closest point on line in 3D cartessian
- `q` is `q'` corrected by spherical projection

So:

1. **convert points to 3D cartessian coordinates**
2. **compute perpendicular distance from point and line**

   - `q'=p0+(dot(p-p0,p1-p0)*(p1-p0)/(|p-p0|*|p1-p0|))`
   - `perpendicular_distance = |p-q'|`
3. **find segment with smallest perpendicular_distance**

   and use only it for the rest of bullets
4. **compute `q`**

   If you use **sphere** instead of **ellipsoid** then you already know the radius if not then either compute the radius algebraically or use average:

   ```
   r=0.5*(|p0-(0,0,0)|+|p1-(0,0,0)|)
   ```

   assuming `(0,0,0)` is Earth's center. You can also be more precise if you weight by position:

   ```
   w=|q'-p0|/|p1-p0|
   r=(1-w)*|p0-(0,0,0)|+w*|p1-(0,0,0)|
   ```

   now just correct the position of `q'`

   ```
   q=q'*r/|q'|
   ```

   set vector `q'` as `q` with size `r` if it is not obvious enough. Also `|p0-(0,0,0)|=|p0|` obviously but I wanted to be sure you get how I got it ...
5. **convert `q` from Cartesian to spherical coordinates**

**[Notes]**

- `|a|` is size of vector `a` done like: `|a|=sqrt(ax*ax+ay*ay+az*az)`
- `dot(a,b)` is dot product of vectors `a,b` done like: `dot(a,b)=(a.b)=ax*bx+ay*by+az*bz`

  if your path is not too complex shaped then you can use binary search to find the closest segment.
  For distance comparison you do not need the `sqrt` ...

Answer (score 0):

Find the path segment which is closest to the current position.

[Distance from point to a line](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_from_a_point_to_a_line)

Comment: Thanks, but lat, lon are not Euclidean geometry and I'm trying to project it onto the path segment.

Comment: If the line passes through two points P1=(x1,y1) and P2=(x2,y2) then the distance of (x0,y0) from the line is abs((y2-y1)*x0-(x2-x1)*y0+x2*y1-y2*x1)/sqrt((y2-y1)*(y2-y1)+(x2-x1)*(x2-x1))

Comment: Latitude and longitude (spherical coordinates on a 3D sphere surface) are not the same as the 2D Euclidean coordinates.

Comment: It should be close enough, and much better than searching for the nearest two (adjacent?) points, like you tried.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 Check out [this demo](http://wtp2.appspot.com/cSnapToRouteDemo.html) (linked from the accepted answer of he question I mentioned above). The point snapping is done by the function `getClosestPointOnLines()` in [this javascript file](http://wtp2.appspot.com/cSnapToRoute.js). The calculations are all done in 2D.