# determinate: is point on line segment

Tags: line, point, segment

I am trying to code a java methods which returns a Boolean true if a point(x,y) is on a line segment and false if not.

I tried this:

```
public static boolean OnDistance(MyLocation a, MyLocation b, MyLocation queryPoint) {

    double value = java.lang.Math.signum((a.mLongitude - b.mLongitude) * (queryPoint.mLatitude - a.mLatitude)
            - (b.mLatitude - a.mLatitude) * (queryPoint.mLongitude - a.mLongitude));
    double compare = 1;
    if (value == compare) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: i found a solution with 12 if-conditions - but i think thats not the smart way ...

Comment: Since the fields are called `mLongitude` and `mLatitude`, do you want to do this on a sphere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not **JAVA** coder so I stick to math behind ... For starters let assume you are on plane (not sphere surface)

1. **I would use Vector math so let:**

   `a,b` - be the line endpoints

   `q`   - queried point

   `c=q-a` - queried line direction vector

   `d=b-a` - line direction vector
2. **use dot product for parameter extraction**

   ```
   t=dot(c,d)/(|c|*|d|)
   ```

   `t` is line parameter `<0,1>` if out of range `q` is not inside line

   `|c|=sqrt(c.x*c.x+c.y*c.y)` size of vector

   `dot(c,d)=c.x*d.x+c.y*d.y` scalar vector multiply
3. **now compute corresponding point on line**

   ```
   e=a+(t*d)
   ```

   `e` is the closest point to `q` on the line `ab`
4. **compute perpendicular distance of `q` and `ab`**

   ```
   l=|q-e|;
   ```

   if `(l>treshold)` then `q` is not on line `ab` else it is on the line `ab`. The threshold is the max distance from line you are still accepting as inside line. No need to have `l` sqrt-ed the threshold constant can be powered by 2 instead for speed.
5. **if you add all this to single equation**

   then some things will simplify itself (hope did not make some silly math mistake)

   ```
   l=|(q-a)-(b-a)*(dot(q-a,b-a)/|b-a|^2)|;
   return (l<=treshold);
   ```

   or

   ```
   l=|c-(d*dot(c,d)/|d|^2)|;
   return (l<=treshold);
   ```

   As you can see we do not even need `sqrt` for this :)

**[Notes]**

If you need spherical or ellipsoidal surface instead then you need to specify it closer which it is what are the semi axises. The line become arc/curve and need some corrections which depends on the shape of surface see

- [Projecting a point onto a path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30934704/2521214)

but can be done also by approximation and may be also by binary search of point `e` see:

- [mine approx class in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29166819/2521214)

The vector math used can be found here at the end:

- [Understanding 4x4 homogenous transform matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28084380/2521214)

**Here 3D C++ implementation (with different names):**

[image: overview]

```cpp
double distance_point_axis(double *p,double *p0,double *dp)
    {
    int i;
    double l,d,q[3];
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) q[i]=p[i]-p0[i];                  // q = p-p0
    for (l=0.0,i=0;i<3;i++) l+=dp[i]*dp[i];             // l = |dp|^2
    for (d=0.0,i=0;i<3;i++) d+=q[i]*dp[i];              // d = dot(q,dp)
    if (l<1e-10) d=0.0; else d/=l;                      // d = dot(q,dp)/|dp|^2
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) q[i]-=dp[i]*d;                    // q=q-dp*dot(q,dp)/|dp|^2
    for (l=0.0,i=0;i<3;i++) l+=q[i]*q[i]; l=sqrt(l);    // l = |q|
    return l;
    }
```

Where `p0[3]` is any point on axis and `dp[3]` is direction vector of axis. The `p[3]` is the queried point you want the distance to axis for.