# How to get diagonal line of a cube in a point cloud?

Tags: python, opengl, point-clouds

I have a point cloud of a cube. I created it with random(), so all x,y,z points are between 0 and 1. I created the cube like that.

```
import numpy as np
import open3d
import random

listPoints = []

for i in range(10000):
    x = random.random()
    y = random.random()
    z = random.random()
    listPoints.append([x,y,z])

arrayPoints = np.asarray(listPoints) 

point_cloud = open3d.PointCloud()
point_cloud.points = open3d.Vector3dVector(arrayPoints)
open3d.draw_geometries([point_cloud])
```

[image: Cube]

Now I want to get the points on the diagonal line. I now how to get points perpendicular to a point. I need to multiply some values depanding on degrees but I couldn't figure out how to do it. The code I use to get perpendicular to middle of the cube: (Y is 0.5 so I keep it static and check all points that has 0.5 Y value)

```
listPoints2 = []

minimumY = 0.5 - 0.02
maximumY = 0.5 + 0.02

for i in range(10000):
    if(listPoints[i][1] < maximumY and listPoints[i][1] > minimumY):
        listPoints2.append([listPoints[i][0],listPoints[i][1],listPoints[i][2]])

arrayPoints2 = np.asarray(listPoints2) 

point_cloud2 = open3d.PointCloud()
point_cloud2.points = open3d.Vector3dVector(arrayPoints2)
open3d.draw_geometries([point_cloud2])
```

[image: Cube]

My final output with perpendicular points. I want it to be angled like diagonal line.

[image: Cube]

With what should I multiply my values to get diagonal line?

Comment: I added animated GIF... on static preview the diagonals shape is not as nicely visible...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need is to compute perpendicular distance of a point to axis see:

- [perpendicular distance of point to line/axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32776408/2521214)

From that you just test all points to be close enough to each of the 4 diagonals of cube. In **C++** (sorry not a Python coder) it looks like this:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
const int n=10000;  // points
const int n3=n+n+n; // points*dimensions
double pnt[n3];     // points x,y,z ...
DWORD  col[n];      // colors rgba, ...
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
double distance_point_axis(double *p,double *p0,double *dp)
    {
    int i;
    double l,d,q[3];
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) q[i]=p[i]-p0[i];                  // q = p-p0
    for (l=0.0,i=0;i<3;i++) l+=dp[i]*dp[i];             // l = |dp|^2
    for (d=0.0,i=0;i<3;i++) d+=q[i]*dp[i];              // d = dot(q,dp)
    if (l<1e-10) d=0.0; else d/=l;                      // d = dot(q,dp)/|dp|^2
    for (i=0;i<3;i++) q[i]-=dp[i]*d;                    // q=q-dp*dot(q,dp)/|dp|^2
    for (l=0.0,i=0;i<3;i++) l+=q[i]*q[i]; l=sqrt(l);    // l = |q|
    return l;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void pnt_init()
    {
    Randomize();
    int i,i3,j;
    double r=0.1;  // radius of diagonals cylinders
    double diag[4*6]=
        {
        // p0        dp
        0.0,0.0,0.0, +1.0,+1.0,+1.0, // diagonal 1
        0.0,1.0,0.0, +1.0,-1.0,+1.0, // diagonal 2
        1.0,0.0,0.0, -1.0,+1.0,+1.0, // diagonal 3
        1.0,1.0,0.0, -1.0,-1.0,+1.0, // diagonal 4
        };
    // compute some uniformly random points <0,1>
    for (i3=0;i3<n3;i3++) pnt[i3]=Random();
    // compute color
    for (i=0,i3=0;i<n;i++,i3+=3)
        {
        // graysh
        col[i]=0x00303030;
        // diagonals
        j=0;
        if (distance_point_axis(pnt+i3,diag+j+0,diag+j+3)<r) col[i]|=0x00FF0000; j+=6;
        if (distance_point_axis(pnt+i3,diag+j+0,diag+j+3)<r) col[i]|=0x0000FF00; j+=6;
        if (distance_point_axis(pnt+i3,diag+j+0,diag+j+3)<r) col[i]|=0x000000FF; j+=6;
        if (distance_point_axis(pnt+i3,diag+j+0,diag+j+3)<r) col[i]|=0x00FF00FF; j+=6;
        }
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void gl_draw()
    {
    int i,i3;
    static double ang=0.0; ang+=2.5; if (ang>360.0) ang-=360.0;
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glTranslatef(-0.5,-0.5,-5.0);
    glRotatef(ang,0.5,0.5,0.5);

    // render points froma list
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    for (i=0,i3=0;i<n;i++,i3+=3)
        {
        glColor4ubv((BYTE*)(col+i));
        glVertex3dv(pnt+i3);
        }
    glEnd();

//  glFlush();
    glFinish();
    SwapBuffers(hdc);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So I declared 4 axes `diag[4*6]` (starting point and direction vector) and just set color of each point that is near to predefined RGB color...

**Here preview:**

[image: preview]

**And GIF animation:**

[image: animation]

In case you want something simpler then main diagonal of your cube is

```
x = y = z
```

so simply test

```
fabs(x-y)+fabs(x-z)+fabs(y-z) <= 1e-2
```

for each point ... the other diagonals are just mirrors so just substitute mirrored `coordinate` with `1-coordinate`