# Calculate approximate location between two locations

Tags: algorithm, math, maps, latitude-longitude

I'm implementing simple navigation, and I need to compute approximate location (GPS) on my route. Route is a list of points, so basically it looks like this:

```
                    (latX, longX)
(lat1, long1) o------o---------------o (lat2, long2)
                     |
                     |
                     o
                     (lat3, long3) - GPS My location
```

I have a two points (lat1, long1) and (lat2, long2) and my location (lat3, long3). How can I compute (latX, longX)?

Comment: Is [orthogonal](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Orthogonal_Projection_Onto_a_Line) [projection](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/62633/orthogonal-projection-of-a-point-onto-a-line) what you need? Or you want to account for spherical geometry?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429562/find-a-point-in-a-polyline-which-is-closest-to-a-latlng provides a starting point (or indeed most of the work, I think)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Projecting a point onto a path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30925042/projecting-a-point-onto-a-path)

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to give you a sketch of how I would divide the problem into smaller steps.

1. Consider the Earth as a perfect 3D sphere of radius `r`.
2. Transform positions given by `(lat, long)` pairs into 3D points `(x, y, z)` on the surface of the sphere, i.e., with `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2`. You will also need the inverse transformation to get back to `(lat, long)` coordinates.
3. Lets put (using 2 above)

   P1 := (x1, y1, z1) <-> (lat1, long1)

   P2 := (x2, y2, z2) <-> (lat2, long2)

   P3 := (x3, y3, z3) <-> (lat3, long3)

   P := (x, y, z) <-> (latX, longX)
4. Let `H` be the plane containing the origin (at the center of the Earth) and the points `P1` and `P2`. Note that `H` intersects the surface of the sphere in the path that joins `P1` with `P2` as in your illustration.
5. Let `(a, b, c)` perpendicular to `H`. You can find it by solving the matrix equation `Mv = 0`, where `M` is the matrix whose rows are `(x1, y1, z1)` and `(x2, y2, z2)` and `v` is the unknown column with coordinates `(a, b, c)`.
6. Let `Q = (x3, y3, z3) + u*(a, b, c)`, where `u` is the coefficient for which `Q = (q1, q2, q3)` lines in `H`. You can calculate `u` by solving the matrix equation `Mv = P3`, where `M` is the `3x3` matrix with columns `(x1, y1, z1)`, `(x2, y2, z2)` and `(-a, -b, -c)`, `v` is the unknown column `(s, t, u)` and `P3` stands for the column `(x3, y3, z3)`.
7. Let `P = w*Q`, where `w` is the coefficient for which `P = (x, y, z)` with `x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2`.
8. Use the inverse of the transformation mentioned in step 2 above to compute `(latX, longX) <-> (x, y, z)`.