# Python: point on a line closest to third point

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a line/vector between two XY points (p1 and p2) and a third XY point (p3) that is outside the line. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40970478/python-3-5-2-distance-from-a-point-to-a-line) I know how to get the distance of that point to the line. But what I'm actually looking for is a point (p4) on that line that is in a minimum distance (d) to the third point (p3). I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32281168/find-a-point-on-a-line-closest-to-a-third-point-javascript), but I feel it's not the correct solution. Maybe there's something included in Numpy or Python?

[image: distance of a point to a line including crossing point]

According to @allo I tried the following. You can download my code as [Python file](http://www.matthias-heise.eu/stackoverflow/point_to_line.py) or [Jupyter Notebook](http://www.matthias-heise.eu/stackoverflow/point_to_line.ipynb) (both Python3).

```
points = [[1, 1], [3, 1], [2.5, 2], [2.5, 1]]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(6,6)

x, y = zip(*points[:2])
l1, = ax.plot(x,y, color='blue')
scatter1 = ax.scatter(x=x,y=y, color='blue', marker='x', s=80, alpha=1.0)

x, y = zip(*points[2:])
l2, = ax.plot(x,y, color='red')
scatter2 = ax.scatter(x=x,y=y, color='red', marker='x', s=80, alpha=1.0)

p1 = Vector2D(*points[0])
p2 = Vector2D(*points[1])
p3 = Vector2D(*points[2])

p1p2 = p2.sub_vector(p1)
p1p3 = p3.sub_vector(p1)

angle_p1p2_p1p3 = p1p2.get_angle_radians(p1p3)
length_p1p3 = p1p3.get_length()
length_p1p2 = p1p2.get_length()

p4 = p1.add_vector(p1p2.multiply(p1p3.get_length()/p1p2.get_length()).multiply(math.cos(p1p2.get_angle_radians(p1p3))))

#p4 = p1 + p1p2 * length(p1p3)/length(p1p2)*cos(angle(p1p2, p1p3))

p4 = p1.add_vector(p1p2.multiply(length_p1p3/length_p1p2*math.cos(angle_p1p2_p1p3)))
p4
```

Which results in p4 = **(1.8062257748298551, 1.0)** but should obviously be **(2.5, 1.0)**.

[image: point p4 to line p1p2]

Comment: How are the lines and pt stored?

Comment: Have a look at [shapely](https://github.com/Toblerity/Shapely)

Comment: The points are stored as columns longitude and latitude in a Pandas Dataframe whereas I can convert that to three columns XYZ too. Thanks for the hint on shapely. Will have a look.

Comment: So, the closest pt `p4` would be one of the points in the existing dataframe and we just need to find it?

Answer (score 9):

#### Analytical Geometry

Let's start with the assigned line, we define the line in terms of two points on it `(x1, y1)` and `(x2, y2)`.

With `dx = x2-x1` and `dy = y2-y1` we can formally write every point on the line as `(x12, y12) = (x1, y1) + a*(dx, dy)` where `a` is a real number.

Using an analogous notation a point on the line passing in `(x3, y3)` and perpendicular to the assigned one is `(x34, y34) = (x3, y3) + b*(-dy, +dx)`.

To find the intersection we have to impose `(x12, y12) = (x34, y34)` or
`(x1, y1) + a*(dx, dy) = (x3, y3) + b*(-dy, +dx)`.

Writing separately the equations for `x` and `y`

```
y1 + a dy - y3 - b dx = 0
x1 + a dx + b dy - x3 = 0
```

it is a linear system in `a` and `b` whose solution is

```
a = (dy y3 - dy y1 + dx x3 - dx x1) / (dy^2 + dx^2)
b = (dy x3 - dy x1 - dx y3 + dx y1) / (dy^2 + dx^2)
```

The coordinates of the closest point to `(x3, y3)` lying on the line
are `(x1+a*dx, y1+a*dy)` — you need to compute only the coefficient `a`.

Numerically speaking, the determinant of the linear system is `dx**2+dy**2` so you have problems only when the two initial points are extremely close to each other with respect to their distance w/r to the third point.

#### Python Implementation

We use a 2-uple of floats to represent a 2D point and we define a function whose arguments are 3 2-uples representing the points that define the line (`p1, p2`) and the point (`p3`) that determines the position of `p4` on said line.

```
In [16]: def p4(p1, p2, p3):
    ...:     x1, y1 = p1
    ...:     x2, y2 = p2
    ...:     x3, y3 = p3
    ...:     dx, dy = x2-x1, y2-y1
    ...:     det = dx*dx + dy*dy
    ...:     a = (dy*(y3-y1)+dx*(x3-x1))/det
    ...:     return x1+a*dx, y1+a*dy
```

To test the implementation I am using the three points used by the OP
to demonstrate their issues with this problem:

```
In [17]: p4((1.0, 1.0), (3.0, 1.0), (2.5, 2))
Out[17]: (2.5, 1.0)
```

It seems that the result of `p4(...)` coincides with the OP expectation.

---

#### A Matplotlib Example

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def p(p1, p2, p3):
    (x1, y1), (x2, y2), (x3, y3) = p1, p2, p3
    dx, dy = x2-x1, y2-y1
    det = dx*dx + dy*dy
    a = (dy*(y3-y1)+dx*(x3-x1))/det
    return x1+a*dx, y1+a*dy

p1, p2, p3 = (2, 4), (7, 3), (1, 1)
p4 = p(p1, p2, p3)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# if we are after  right angles, anything else would be wrong
ax.set_aspect(1)

plt.plot(*zip(p1, p2, p4, p3), marker='*')
```

Comment: I’m working on a similar solution. Thus rotating the original vector p1p2 by 90 degrees and adding it to p3 thus creating a new vector that is perpendicular to p1p2. Then it’s easy to get the intersection between both vector which is p4.

Comment: It seems to work only with vertical lines. Try with [1.0, 0.45], [10.0, 0.03], [1.64, 0.28]

Comment: @VincenzoLavorini Maybe `ax.set_aspect(1)`?

Comment: @gboffi thank you! So the problem was just graphical: the scale of X and Y was not the same, so the visual effect was of not being perpendicular. Setting the aspect as stated solves this.

Comment: @VincenzoLavorini Is my answer correct and useful?

Answer (score 3):

Shapely's [distance()](http://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html?highlight=linestring#object.distance) function returns the minimum distance:

```
>>> from shapely.geometry import LineString as shLs
>>> from shapely.geometry import Point as shPt
>>> l = shLs([ (1,1), (3,1)])
>>> p = shPt(2,2)
>>> dist = p.distance(l)
1.0
>>> l.interpolate(dist).wkt
'POINT (2 1)'
```

[image]

Comment: But your calculation of the last point is wrong because it takes the distance that is only valid for p3 to l.

Comment: Sorry, i messed up the coordinates for the Linestring - the second point has to be (3,1) not (1,3) :)

Comment: Still, your last line of code is wrong. In your Illustration the result will be correct, but change to 1,2 and you will get a wrong result.

Comment: I added demo-points and demo-code to my original question. Try those points with your code.

Comment: A LineString consists of multiple points, when created just with start/end point shapely just take them into account. Another way to make it could be: converting the linestring into a polygon. Have a look at another [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33324058/7216865)

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is a [vector projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_projection).

The edge `p1p3` is rotated onto the edge `p1p2` and you need to find the correct length of the segment `p1p4`. Then you can just use `p1+FACTOR*p1p2 / length(p1p2)`. The needed factor is given by the cosine of the angle between `p1p2` and `p1p3`. Then you get

```
p4 = p1 + p1p2 * length(p1p3)/length(p1p2)*cos(angle(p1p2, p1p3))
```

Here the two edge cases as example:

- The cosinus is `0` if `p1p3` is orthogonal to `p1p2`, so `p4` lies on `p1`.
- The cosinus is 1 when `p1p3` lies on `p1p2`, so `p1p2` is just scaled by `length(p1p3)/length(p1p2)` to get `p1p4`.

You further can replace the cosinus by the dot product `dot(p1p2 / length(p1p2), p1p3 / length(p1p3)`.

You can find more details and nice illustrations [in the wikibook about linear algebra](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Linear_Algebra/Orthogonal_Projection_Onto_a_Line).

Here an full example derived from your python code. I used numpy instead of Vector2D here.

```
points = [[1, 1], [3, 1], [2.5, 2], [2.5, 1]]
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches(6,6)

x, y = zip(*points[:2])
l1, = ax.plot(x,y, color='blue')
scatter1 = ax.scatter(x=x,y=y, color='blue', marker='x', s=80, alpha=1.0)

x, y = zip(*points[2:])
l2, = ax.plot(x,y, color='red')
scatter2 = ax.scatter(x=x,y=y, color='red', marker='x', s=80, alpha=1.0)

p1 = np.array(points[0])
p2 = np.array(points[1])
p3 = np.array(points[2])

p1p2 = p2 - p1
p1p3 = p3 - p1

p4 = p1 + p1p2 / np.linalg.norm(p1p2) * np.linalg.norm(p1p3) * ((p1p2/np.linalg.norm(p1p2)).T * (p1p3/np.linalg.norm(p1p3)))

p1, p2, p3, p4, p1p2, p1p3
```

We can shorten the `p4` line a bit like this, using the linearity of the scalar product:

```
p4 = p1 + p1p2 / np.linalg.norm(p1p2) * ((p1p2/np.linalg.norm(p1p2)).T * (p1p3))
p4 = p1 + p1p2 / np.linalg.norm(p1p2)**2 * (p1p2.T * (p1p3))
```

Comment: Thx, will test that!

Comment: I tried that, but somehow I get wrong results. If you use those points: [[1, 1], [3, 1], [2.5, 2]], then the result p4 is (1.8062257748298551, 1.0), but should be (2.5, 1). I will add my code to the original question.