# Google map API v.3 find nearest point from one point to point on polyline

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I`ve got a map with a polyline. The server will responds me with a LatLng point on a map. I need to check if the point from the server situated on a polyline edge. If not, i need to find the nearest point on the polyline and place a marker on the nearest point on the polyline. For example, if the server responds me with a point A, i need to place a marker to a point B.

[image]

I find a good library http://wtp2.appspot.com/cSnapToRouteDemo.html, but this library is for Google API ver. 2, and i'm using Google API ver. 3. Is there any alternative for Google API ver. 3 ? Thank's.

Answer (score 2):

Found an easier solution.Using turf.js.Just use your polyline coordinates to create turf line and marker position for creating turf point.

then;

```
var line = turf.lineString(Your polyline coordinates in GeoJson array);
var pt = turf.point([Marker_Lon, Marker_Lat]);
var snapped = turf.pointOnLine(line, pt);
var pstnOnLine = { lat: snapped.geometry.coordinates[1], lng: snapped.geometry.coordinates[0] };
var distToLine = snapped.properties.dist
```

This way you can calculate the distance and coordinates on your polyline easily.

You can find out more from [Turf website](http://turfjs.org/docs/#pointonline).

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps Javascript API has a [Geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry).

The Geometry library has a `isLocationOnEdge` function. See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry#isLocationOnEdge).

> To determine whether a point falls on or near a polyline, or on or near the edge of a polygon, pass the point, the polyline/polygon, and optionally a tolerance value in degrees to `google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()`. The function returns true if the distance between the point and the closest point on the line or edge falls within the specified tolerance. The default tolerance value is 10<sup>-9</sup> degrees.

You must include the library this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">
</script>
```

And if you need more than one library, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry,places">
</script>
```

Full documentation is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries).

---

If you need to find the point on the Polyline, you can use this ported to v3 version of the library you mentioned in your question:

```
var mapRoute;

var rtPoints;
var centerMAP = new google.maps.LatLng(-7.402438, 110.446957);

function gLatLngFromEN(e, n) {
    var ogbLL = NEtoLL(e, n);
    var pc = OGBToWGS84(ogbLL.lat, ogbLL.lon, 0);
    return new google.maps.LatLng(pc.lat, pc.lon);
}

function routeMap() {

    mapRoute = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapRoute'), {
        center: centerMAP,
        zoom: 14,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    });
    mapRoute.setCenter(gLatLngFromEN(469000, 169000), 13);

    var rtPoints = new Array();
    rtPoints.push(gLatLngFromEN(468000, 168000));
    rtPoints.push(gLatLngFromEN(468000, 170000));
    rtPoints.push(gLatLngFromEN(470000, 170000));
    rtPoints.push(gLatLngFromEN(470000, 168000));
    var rtPoly = new google.maps.Polyline({
        path: rtPoints,
        strokeColor: "#0000FF",
        strokeWeight: 3,
        map: mapRoute
    });
    var container = document.createElement("div");
    container.style.fontFamily = 'Arial';
    container.style.fontSize = 'XX-Small';

    var ptr = document.createElement("INPUT");
    ptr.style.width = "100px";
    ptr.type = "Text";
    ptr.readOnly = true;
    ptr.id = "distPtr";
    container.appendChild(ptr);

    document.getElementById("control").appendChild(container);


    google.maps.event.addListener(mapRoute, 'mousemove', function (point) {
        document.getElementById('distPtr').value = Math.round(bdccGeoDistanceToPolyMtrs(rtPoly, point.latLng));
    });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', routeMap);


// Code to find the distance in metres between a lat/lng point and a polyline of lat/lng points
// All in WGS84. Free for any use.
//
// Bill Chadwick 2007
// updated to Google Maps API v3, Lawrence Ross 2014

    // Construct a bdccGeo from its latitude and longitude in degrees
    function bdccGeo(lat, lon) 
    {
      var theta = (lon * Math.PI / 180.0);
      var rlat = bdccGeoGeocentricLatitude(lat * Math.PI / 180.0);
      var c = Math.cos(rlat);   
      this.x = c * Math.cos(theta);
      this.y = c * Math.sin(theta);
      this.z = Math.sin(rlat);      
    }
    bdccGeo.prototype = new bdccGeo();

    // internal helper functions =========================================

      // Convert from geographic to geocentric latitude (radians).
    function bdccGeoGeocentricLatitude(geographicLatitude) 
    {
      var flattening = 1.0 / 298.257223563;//WGS84
        var f = (1.0 - flattening) * (1.0 - flattening);
      return Math.atan((Math.tan(geographicLatitude) * f));
    }

    // Convert from geocentric to geographic latitude (radians)
    function bdccGeoGeographicLatitude (geocentricLatitude) 
    {
      var flattening = 1.0 / 298.257223563;//WGS84
        var f = (1.0 - flattening) * (1.0 - flattening);
      return Math.atan(Math.tan(geocentricLatitude) / f);
    }

     // Returns the two antipodal points of intersection of two great
     // circles defined by the arcs geo1 to geo2 and
     // geo3 to geo4. Returns a point as a Geo, use .antipode to get the other point
    function bdccGeoGetIntersection( geo1,  geo2,  geo3,  geo4) 
    {
      var geoCross1 = geo1.crossNormalize(geo2);
      var geoCross2 = geo3.crossNormalize(geo4);
      return geoCross1.crossNormalize(geoCross2);
    }

    //from Radians to Meters
    function bdccGeoRadiansToMeters(rad)
    {
      return rad * 6378137.0; // WGS84 Equatorial Radius in Meters
    }

    //from Meters to Radians
    function bdccGeoMetersToRadians(m)
    {
      return m / 6378137.0; // WGS84 Equatorial Radius in Meters
    }

    // properties =================================================


    bdccGeo.prototype.getLatitudeRadians = function() 
    {
      return (bdccGeoGeographicLatitude(Math.atan2(this.z,
        Math.sqrt((this.x * this.x) + (this.y * this.y)))));
    }

    bdccGeo.prototype.getLongitudeRadians = function() 
    {
      return (Math.atan2(this.y, this.x));
    }

    bdccGeo.prototype.getLatitude = function() 
    {
      return this.getLatitudeRadians()  * 180.0 / Math.PI;
    }

    bdccGeo.prototype.getLongitude = function() 
    {
      return this.getLongitudeRadians()  * 180.0 / Math.PI ;
    }

    // Methods =================================================

        //Maths
    bdccGeo.prototype.dot = function( b) 
    {
      return ((this.x * b.x) + (this.y * b.y) + (this.z * b.z));
    }

        //More Maths
    bdccGeo.prototype.crossLength = function( b) 
    {
      var x = (this.y * b.z) - (this.z * b.y);
      var y = (this.z * b.x) - (this.x * b.z);
      var z = (this.x * b.y) - (this.y * b.x);
      return Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z));
    }

    //More Maths
    bdccGeo.prototype.scale = function( s) 
    {
        var r = new bdccGeo(0,0);
        r.x = this.x * s;
        r.y = this.y * s;
        r.z = this.z * s;
      return r;
    }

        // More Maths
    bdccGeo.prototype.crossNormalize = function( b) 
    {
      var x = (this.y * b.z) - (this.z * b.y);
      var y = (this.z * b.x) - (this.x * b.z);
      var z = (this.x * b.y) - (this.y * b.x);
      var L = Math.sqrt((x * x) + (y * y) + (z * z));
      var r = new bdccGeo(0,0);
      r.x = x / L;
      r.y = y / L;
      r.z = z / L;
      return r;
    }

    // point on opposite side of the world to this point
    bdccGeo.prototype.antipode = function() 
    {
      return this.scale(-1.0);
    }






        //distance in radians from this point to point v2
    bdccGeo.prototype.distance = function( v2) 
    {
      return Math.atan2(v2.crossLength(this), v2.dot(this));
    }

    //returns in meters the minimum of the perpendicular distance of this point from the line segment geo1-geo2
    //and the distance from this point to the line segment ends in geo1 and geo2 
    bdccGeo.prototype.distanceToLineSegMtrs = function(geo1, geo2)
    {            

      //point on unit sphere above origin and normal to plane of geo1,geo2
      //could be either side of the plane
      var p2 = geo1.crossNormalize(geo2); 

      // intersection of GC normal to geo1/geo2 passing through p with GC geo1/geo2
      var ip = bdccGeoGetIntersection(geo1,geo2,this,p2); 

      //need to check that ip or its antipode is between p1 and p2
      var d = geo1.distance(geo2);
      var d1p = geo1.distance(ip);
      var d2p = geo2.distance(ip);
      //window.status = d + ", " + d1p + ", " + d2p;
      if ((d >= d1p) && (d >= d2p)) 
        return bdccGeoRadiansToMeters(this.distance(ip));
      else
      {
        ip = ip.antipode(); 
        d1p = geo1.distance(ip);
        d2p = geo2.distance(ip);
      }
      if ((d >= d1p) && (d >= d2p)) 
        return bdccGeoRadiansToMeters(this.distance(ip)); 
      else 
        return bdccGeoRadiansToMeters(Math.min(geo1.distance(this),geo2.distance(this))); 
    }

        // distance in meters from GLatLng point to GPolyline or GPolygon poly
        function bdccGeoDistanceToPolyMtrs(poly, point)
        {
            var d = 999999999;
            var i;
            var p = new bdccGeo(point.lat(),point.lng());
            for(i=0; i<(poly.getPath().getLength()-1); i++)
                 {
                    var p1 = poly.getPath().getAt(i);
                    var l1 = new bdccGeo(p1.lat(),p1.lng());
                    var p2 = poly.getPath().getAt(i+1);
                    var l2 = new bdccGeo(p2.lat(),p2.lng());
                    var dp = p.distanceToLineSegMtrs(l1,l2);
                    if(dp < d)
                        d = dp;    
                 }
             return d;
        }

        // get a new GLatLng distanceMeters away on the compass bearing azimuthDegrees
        // from the GLatLng point - accurate to better than 200m in 140km (20m in 14km) in the UK

        function bdccGeoPointAtRangeAndBearing (point, distanceMeters, azimuthDegrees) 
        {
             var latr = point.lat() * Math.PI / 180.0;
             var lonr = point.lng() * Math.PI / 180.0;

             var coslat = Math.cos(latr); 
             var sinlat = Math.sin(latr); 
             var az = azimuthDegrees* Math.PI / 180.0;
             var cosaz = Math.cos(az); 
             var sinaz = Math.sin(az); 
             var dr = distanceMeters / 6378137.0; // distance in radians using WGS84 Equatorial Radius
             var sind = Math.sin(dr); 
             var cosd = Math.cos(dr);

            return new google.maps.LatLng(Math.asin((sinlat * cosd) + (coslat * sind * cosaz)) * 180.0 / Math.PI,
            (Math.atan2((sind * sinaz), (coslat * cosd) - (sinlat * sind * cosaz)) + lonr) * 180.0 / Math.PI); 
        }
```

*Credits to Bill Chadwick 2007 and Lawrence Ross 2014 for the v3 version. And @geocodezip for finding it.*

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x8tbngch/4/)</kbd>

Comment: Thank's for your answer. I have already use google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge() function. But my problem is a bit another. With google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge() i just can check if the passed LatLng is on or not on the polyline. And i want to calculate the LatLng of a nearest point on the polyline depends on the responds LatLng from the server.

Comment: Did you check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429562/find-a-point-in-a-polyline-which-is-closest-to-a-latlng)? It shows a ported to v3 version of the library you mentioned in your question.

Comment: And sorry, I misread this sentence: *Returns true when the difference between the latitude and longitude of the supplied point, and the closest point on the edge, is less than the tolerance.* as I thought it was also returning that point on the polyline. But that's not the case...

Comment: Yes, i find it just now. I`m trying to solve my problem with it's version. Thank you.

Comment: @Edward did you come up with any solutions?