# How to find the nearest coordinate between a certain point and a line on Google Maps?

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps

This question is specifically for Android, but I understand JavaScript as well.
In the image below, A,B and C are known Google Maps coordinates.
I need to find out the coordinate of point X.
The coordinate of point X is the place where the line between A and B is closest to point C.

Is there a way to find X?

[image]

Comment: take a look at this, seems like what you are asking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35746224/google-map-api-v-3-find-nearest-point-from-one-point-to-point-on-polyline

Answer (score 0):

Use 'google.maps.geometry.poly.isLocationOnEdge()' to find out if X is close or on a polyline or polygon.
Pass the C coordinate, A-B points as polyline and a tolerance value - which sets the maximum distance from the polyline is X. It returns true or false.
The actual coordinate of X is not found, but this is what I was actually looking for.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry