# I want to retrieve the latitude and longitude of a location shown in google map route between two locations

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have lat and long of some locations in JSON. I want to spot whether these locations are present in a route shown by google maps.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_google_maps.htm. See this tutorial on how to place markers on maps.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I'd consider to achieve the effect you want:

- Query for a `DirectionResponse` https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#DirectionsResponses
- For each `polyline` of each `step` of each `leg`, test whether your locations are close to the line. For simplicity you can also use the `overview_polyline`. Unfortunately this is not simple to do out-of-the-box using the Maps API alone. Check this thread for inspiration on a manual implementation. [Find a point in a polyline which is closest to a latlng](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429562/find-a-point-in-a-polyline-which-is-closest-to-a-latlng)
- Alternatively, convert the polylines to [GeoJSON](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-polyline), and process using a spatial library such as [JSTS](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/) or [Turf](http://turfjs.org). E.g. the latter provides a [pointOnLine](http://turfjs.org/docs/#pointonline) function.

Comment: Just noticed that you're doing this on Android. In this case JTS https://github.com/locationtech/jts could be useful. In particular, I believe you can test for perpendicular distance to  `LineSegment`s.