# Appending list elements into the correct sorted position

Tags: python, list, sorting, python-3.x

I'm trying to get a list of players within a given radius of a point, and have them sorted by their distance to that point.
Getting the players is simple:

```
players = [
    player for player in Player.instances
    if player.distance(my_point) <= max_radius
]
```

And sorting it goes fine too:

```
return sorted(players, key=lambda player: player.get_distance(my_point))
```

However, calling `player.distance(my_point)` for everyone might get heavy if the server's full of players, so sorting the players afterwards always takes some extra time.
Is there a way to automatically sort the list while appending the players to it, so I wouldn't have to loop twice through everyone and call `getdistance` twice?

Comment: Is your goal to find the closest players, or to always have all players in fully sorted order?

Comment: even if you do you will still be sorting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm attempting to create a function which returns all the players within a radius of a point, sorted by their distance to that point.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes but now I'm calling `player.get_distance(my_point)` twice in the same function, I was wondering if there's a better way?

Comment: there are other ways but they all have a cost, just sorting may just be as good as any.

Comment: Is your main source of worry the cost of `get_distance`?

Comment: @zehnpaard Pretty much yeah, calling it twice for say 200 players

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to using a sorted data structure (as suggested by Martijn Pieters), you could combine the distance info with the player object. You could do that by adding it as an attribute to the player class, or by temporarily combining each player instance with its distance info. Eg,

```
players = []
for player in Player.instances:
    dist = player.distance(my_point)
    if dist <= max_radius:
        players.append((dist, player))

#Sort in order of distance. If two distances match, sort by player.
players.sort()

#Strip out dist info
players = [v for u,v in players]

#or
players = zip(*players)[1]
```

Comment: How does this help inserting another player later on?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I didn't know Markus wanted to do that. I get the feeling that the distance value is a temporary thing, and will need to be recalculated each time the players move. So the current order is only temporary, too.

Comment: @PM2Ring You were right, I don't need such behavior, it's enough if they're sorted once at the moment I call the function.

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen: right, then I misunderstood. You wanted to avoid having to re-calculate the distance for both filtering and sorting. Producing a list with `(distance, player)` tuples is then the right approach.

Answer (score 2):

If the distance indeed is a distance in a Euclidian space, what you could use is a is some kind of space-partitioning algorithm, like [quadtree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) for 2D, or [octree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree) for 3D;

If you have a static set, then there is no need for space partitioning. But if you have a dynamic set with many reference points, or the players are moving, these are way more efficient than calculating distances (`O(kn)` distance calculations) and then calculating the nearest ones for each for at least `O(kn)` operations in total, every single time you calculate the distances.

See also the related [C++ discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509798/finding-nearest-point-in-an-efficient-way).