# Index of hovered element in QGraphicsPathItem

Tags: qt, shapes, qgraphicsview

I have a QGraphicsPathItem which is drawn from a list of cartesian x,y points.

What would be the best (performance wise) method of determining when the cursor is hovered over one of these points I presently iterate through the source list and compare each point with the cursor position.

Regards

Comment: How many `QGraphicsPathItem` do you have? One for each point or one for all the points together? A [mcve] may be useful.

Comment: Each path represent  a trail consisting of hundreds of waypoints. So essentially I want to determine when I'm hovered on a waypoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Qt does not provide a built-in solution for what you want. You should reimplement [`QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#mouseMoveEvent) and check in it which point (if any) is hovered (with a certain margin), i.e. determine which point is within a certain distance of the current mouse position ([`QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent::pos`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscenemouseevent.html#pos)).

The most computation intensive task is determining the closest point. A naive approach is to iterate over all the points, but general [optimised implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509798/finding-nearest-point-in-an-efficient-way) exists:

- [QuadTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree): 2D implementation
- [k-d tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree): Multidimensional implementation
- [Nearest Neighbor Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search): broad overview

Caching the last result and using the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) may be important to improve the performance of this method:

- If currently the mouse hovers a point `P`, the next time you can just validate if it still hovers this point.
- If currently no point is hovered and the nearest point from location `P` (the last mouse position for which you calculated the nearest point) is at a distance `d`, then you should not check if an hover occur if: `norm(P - QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent::pos()) < d - hoverThreshold`

Comment: Thabks mate, used a brute force approach, seems to work fine

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the `QGraphicScene`'s `itemAt()` method to check for graphic items under the cursor.